# Rename PDF file

Tags: kofax

I would like to create a custom module that renames the generated PDF files by taking a generated filename string containg some field values from index fields, batch fields etc.

So when it comes to batch processing i could go for this (`setupTransformator` contains the parsed values from the custom storage strings)

```
    public void ProcessBatch(IBatch batch)
    {
        IACDataElement batchElement = GetBatchElementFromBatch(batch);
        IACDataElementCollection currentDocuments = GetDocumentsFromBatchElement(batchElement);
        IACDataElement customStorageStrings = GetCustomStorageStringsFromBatch(batch);
        IACDataElementCollection batchFields = GetElementsByName(batchElement, ResourcesKofax.BATCH_FIELDS, ResourcesKofax.BATCH_FIELD);

        setupTransformator = new SetupTransformator(customStorageStrings);

        for (int i = 0; i < currentDocuments.Count; i++)
        {
            int currentDocumentIndex = i + 1;
            IACDataElement currentDocument = currentDocuments[currentDocumentIndex];
            IACDataElementCollection indexFields = GetElementsByName(currentDocument, ResourcesKofax.INDEX_FIELDS, ResourcesKofax.INDEX_FIELD);

            string targetFilename = setupTransformator.GetFilename(batchElement, currentDocument, batchFields, indexFields);

            string documentFilePath = currentDocument[ResourcesKofax.PDF_GENERATION_FILE_NAME];

            // rename the PDF file
        }

        batch.BatchClose(KfxDbState.KfxDbBatchReady, KfxDbQueue.KfxDbQueueNext, 0, string.Empty);
    }

    private IACDataElement GetBatchElementFromBatch(IBatch batch)
    {
        IACDataElement rootElement = batch.ExtractRuntimeACDataElement(0);
        return rootElement.FindChildElementByName(ResourcesKofax.BATCH);
    }

    private IACDataElementCollection GetDocumentsFromBatchElement(IACDataElement batchElement)
    {
        return GetElementsByName(batchElement, ResourcesKofax.DOCUMENTS, ResourcesKofax.DOCUMENT);
    }

    private IACDataElement GetCustomStorageStringsFromBatch(IBatch batch)
    {
        IACDataElement setupElement = batch.ExtractSetupACDataElement(0);
        IACDataElementCollection batchClasses = GetElementsByName(setupElement, ResourcesKofax.BATCH_CLASSES, ResourcesKofax.BATCH_CLASS);
        IACDataElement batchClass = batchClasses[1];
        return batchClass.FindChildElementByName(ResourcesKofax.BATCH_CLASS_CUSTOM_STORAGE_STRINGS);
    }

    private IACDataElementCollection GetElementsByName(IACDataElement dataElement, string rootName, string targetName)
    {
        return dataElement.FindChildElementByName(rootName).FindChildElementsByName(targetName);
    }
```

Do I have to use the `File.Move` method or is there a method from the Kofax library I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File names should be handled by Export Connectors only. As long as the batch is in the system you shouldn't have their names changed as this could lead to data loss and corruption.

This especially applies when using field values for a PDF's name - since values are subject to change as long as the batch is in the system, how would you accommodate this? Nothing is stopping your users from processing a batch in your custom module and set the batch back to validation and change one or more fields.

Speaking of the Export Connector and its API:

By default, Kofax offers two methods to export a PDF - both on the `ReleaseData` object (this is taken from the API docs):

- `CopyKofaxPDFFile`: Copy the PDF file that belongs to a document into the export PDF path that is defined during export setup.
- `CopyKofaxPDFFileToPath`: Copy the PDF file that belongs to a document into a specified path (the path is a string input argument for this method).

Both methods make use of something that you **could** define during Setup - for example, `CopyKofaxPDFFile` makes use of the `KofaxPDFPath` property. I am not sure if there's a property reserved for the file name.

I usually stick with the `KofaxPDFProperty` exposed during runtime and perform a `File.Copy` operation. I wouldn't recommend moving the file or deleting it as this is something that KC automatically handles once the batch was exported successfully (in theory, there could be another export, or the export might just fail).

Use the `ReleaseData` object to access field values, and string interpolation to define the PDF's final name.

Comment: I think the question is related to custom modules, no? As far as I know the release data object is related to export scripts. Not sure if I am wrong

Comment: Thanks for your comment - and you're right - OP asks for CMs. Naming files should be handled by an Export Connector exclusively, and I edited my answer to explain why.